# Filter data displayed on screen from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js

Im currently working on a project where I need to grab data from a JSON file and display it allowing the user to add an input that should match the expected value

But i want to display different parts or the screen at different times i want the first ID to be displayed first and when the user inputs and presses enter it should display the next lot of information

here is my JSON

```
 var jsonData = {
            id: 1,
            description: 'SCREEN 1',
            screens: [
                {
                   //LOCATION OF THE PART 
                    id: 0,
                    flds: [
                     { id: 0,
                       fldName: 'Location',
                       expected: 'L-MOTA56M',
                       input: 'L-'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                   //PART INFORMATION FOR THE PICKER

                    id: 1,
                    flds: [
                     { id: 0,
                       fldName: 'Part',
                       expected: 'P-1597531',
                       input: 'P-'},

                     { id: 1,
                       fldName: 'Serial',
                       expected: 'S-6571687',
                       input: 'S-'},
                     { id: 2,
                       fldName: 'Qty',
                       expected: 'Q-10',
                       input: 'Q-'}
                     ]
                }]
        };
```

As you can see there is a array of screens with and array of flds inside but I want to filter it buy the screens ID

This is my current HTML :

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>RDT</title>
   </head>

  <style>
  .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  }
  </style>

  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2><span data-bind="text: description"></span></h2>
      <hr/>
    </div>

    <div class="RDT">

      <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'screenTemplate', foreach: screens, as: 'screen' }">
      </ul>

      <script type="text/html" id="screenTemplate">
        <span hidden="true" data-bind="text: id"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'fldTemplate', foreach: flds }"></ul>
      </script>
      <script type="text/html" id="fldTemplate">
        <span data-bind="text: fieldName, "></span>
        <br/>
        <span data-bind="text: expectedValue, style: {color: inputValue() == expectedValue() ? 'lime' : 'red'}"></span>
        <br/>
        <span hidden="true" data-bind="text: inputValue"></span>
        <input data-bind="value: inputValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        <h2>----------------------</h2>
      </script>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <button data-bind="click: saveData">Save Data</button>
    </div>
```

This uses Knockout Templates to display the data from the JSON file

Here is my JavaScript:

```
 <script>           
    $(function () {

      var mapping = {

        'screens': {
          create: function (options) {
            return new screenModel(options.data);
          }
        }
      };

      var screenModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, fieldMapping, self);

      };

      var fieldMapping = {
        'flds': {
          create: function (options) {
            return new fieldModel(options.data);
          }
        }
      };

      var fieldModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.fieldName = ko.observable(data.fldName);
        self.expectedValue = ko.observable(data.expected);
        self.inputValue = ko.observable(data.input);

      };

      var db = rdtApp.TransactionDataContext;
      db.getTransaction("1", function (data) {
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
        console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel));


        // THIS ALL APPLIES TO THE BUTTON ON THE SCREEN
        //IT IS TO START ALL OF THE SAVING PROCESS
        var jsonArray = ko.observableArray();

        saveData = function () {
          var jsonDatas = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel)
          if(confirm('Do you wan to save this data? \n \n' + jsonDatas) == true) {
            jsonArray.push(jsonDatas);
            alert(jsonArray().join('\n \n'));
            console.log(jsonDatas);

          } else {
            console.log("You pressed Cancel");
          }
        }  

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

      });

    });

    </script>
```

This grabs the data from the JSON file and maps it to work with my templates but at the moment it just displayes all of the information at once

[image: Screen 1]

I would like it to only display the Location(screens ID 0) section first and once that has been entered I want it to then display the part, serial and QTY(screens ID 1)

Can anybody help me achieve this

Comment: There is a visible binding:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html.  Perhaps it helps to you.

Comment: @joseLuis I have read through it a few time and tried different solutions but still have not managed the desired effect

Comment: You're going to want a `currentScreen` observable in your viewmodel. Use the `data-bind="visible: currentScreen() == $index()"` or some such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out

Needed to use the `<!-- ko if: --> <!--/ko-->`

as shown here

```
<!-- ko if: showFlds -->
        <span data-bind="text: id, as: 'id'"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'fldTemplate', foreach: flds } "></ul>
<!--/ko-->
```

and then add this to the screenModel

```
self.showFlds = ko.computed(function () {
         return (data.id == 0);
         });
```

and all I need to do now I hit enter to change the id number

Finally got it working